# Recibir el ajax en controlador

Tags: laravel

Necesito recibir lo que trae `carrito`.

Tengo este AJAX

```
$.ajax({
             headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
             url: "{{ route('web.recibePresupuesto') }}",
             type: "post",
             dataType: "html",
             data: {
                carrito,
                'subtotal': $("#subtotal").html(),
                'iva': $("#totalIva").html(),
                'total': $("#totalPrecio").html(),
                'persona': $("#persona").val(),
                'apellidos': $("#apellidos").val(),
                'telefono': $("#telefono").val(),
                'email': $("#email").val(),
                'poblacion': $("#poblacion").val(),
                'postal': $("#postal").val(),
                'parcela': $("#parcela").val()
             },
             beforeSend: function(){
               $("#mensaje").html("Procesando, espere por favor...")
             },
             success: function (res){
               $("#mensaje").html("Recibido");
             }
         });
```

Lo que necesito recibir bien en mi contralador es `carrito`. Que si me meto en el inspector de elemento viene de este modo.

```
{"id":"1","producto":"Contenedor de 20 pies","precio":"20000"}
```

Es como un carrito donde se va creando una lista. Lo que necesito saber como traer lo que lleva carrito al controlador para luego en la vista hacer un `foreach` con todo lo que lleva `carrito`

Intento traerlo así de este modo pero sin éxito:

```
$productos = $_POST['carrito'];
```

Y luego lo mando a la vista con `compact` pero nada

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione de este modo

Lo recibo en el controlador del siguiente modo:

```
$productos = collect($_POST['carrito']);
```

Paso la variable a través de `compact` a la vista y luego en la vista:

Lo imprimo así `{{ $elemento['producto'] }}`

Espero que sea lo correcto, al menos funciona.